# Launch Jasper Report Studio and import projects via command line

Tags: eclipse, command-line, jaspersoft-studio

I need to launch [Jasper Reports Studio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) and specify a custom workspace directory and **import all existing projects**.

I'm trying this commands but without success:

```
"Jasper Studio.exe" -data /path/to/my/workspace -import /path/to/my/workspace/project1 -import /path/to/my/workspace/project2
```

or

```
"Jasper Studio.exe" -data /path/to/my/workspace -import project1 -import project2
```

I already tried too use the `eclipsec.exe` with these arguments, but the Jasper Studio always starts clean, without my projects (project1 and project2), but with an default project created by the studio called *My Reports*.

I was basing my tries on this [link](https://developer.arm.com/docs/dui0478/u/arm-ds-5-tutorials/using-eclipse-from-the-command-line-to-clean-and-build-your-projects) but it seems to be not official.

Comment: Found a solution: https://github.com/seeq12/eclipse-import-projects-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use a plugin in Jasper Studio to be able to import projects from a directory via command line:

https://github.com/seeq12/eclipse-import-projects-plugin